# python NoneType attribute error

Tags: python

I am getting "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'" with following code. Pls help in resolving same.

```
def search_albums(self, query, _dir = None):
    from pprint import pprint
    url = self.urls['search_albums_new']
    url = url.format(query = query)
    response = self._get_url_contents(url)
    albums = response.json()['album']
    if albums:
        albums_list = map(lambda x:[x['album_id'],x['title'], x['language'], x['seokey'], x['release_date'],','.join(map(lambda y:y['name'], x.get('artists',[])[:2])) ,x['trackcount']], albums)
        tabledata = [['S No.', 'Album Title', 'Album Language', 'Release Date', 'Artists', 'Track Count']]
        for idx, value in enumerate(albums_list):
            tabledata.append([str(idx), value[1], value[2], value[4], value[5], value[6]])
        table = AsciiTable(tabledata)
        print table.table
        idx = int(raw_input('Which album do you wish to download? Enter S No. :'))
        album_details_url = self.urls['album_details']
        album_details_url = album_details_url.format(album_id = albums_list[idx][0])
        response = requests.get(album_details_url , headers = {'deviceType':'AndroidApp', 'appVersion':'V5'})
        tracks = response.json()['tracks']
        tracks_list = map(lambda x:[x['track_title'].strip(),x['track_id'],x['album_id'],x['album_title'], ','.join(map(lambda y:y['name'], x['artist'])), x['duration']], tracks)
        print 'List of tracks for ', albums_list[idx][1]
        tabledata = [['S No.', 'Track Title', 'Track Artist']]
        for idy, value in enumerate(tracks_list):
            tabledata.append([str(idy), value[0], value[4]])
        tabledata.append([str(idy+1), 'Enter this to download them all.',''])
        table = AsciiTable(tabledata)
        print table.table
        print 'Downloading tracks to %s folder'%albums_list[idx][3]
        ids = raw_input('Please enter csv of S no. to download:')
        while not self._check_input(ids, len(tracks_list)) or not ids:
            print 'Oops!! You made some error in entering input'
            ids = raw_input('Please enter csv of S no. to download:')
        if not _dir:
            _dir = albums_list[idx][3]
        self._check_path(_dir)
        ids = map(int,map(lambda x:x.strip(),ids.split(',')))
        if len(ids) == 1 and ids[0] == idy + 1:
            for item in tracks_list:
                song_url = self._get_song_url(item[1], item[2])
                self._download_track(song_url, item[0].replace(' ','-').strip(), _dir)
        else:
            for i in ids:
                item = tracks_list[i]
                song_url = self._get_song_url(item[1], item[2])
                self._download_track(song_url, item[0].replace(' ','-').strip(), _dir)
    else:
        print 'Ooopsss!!! Sorry no such album found.'
        print 'Why not try another Album? :)'
```

Error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "a-dl.py", line 163, in
>   
>       d.search_albums(args.album)   File "a-dl.py", line 116, in search_albums
>       print table.table   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\terminaltables.py", line 337, in table
>       padded_table_data = self.padded_table_data   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\terminaltables.py", line 326, in
>   padded_table_data
>       height = max([c.count('\n') for c in row] or [0]) + 1 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'

Comment: That's of lot of code! Can you try to shorten this down to an [mcve] so that we can more easily help you?

Comment: your error is not in the current code at all.

Comment: max([c.count('\n') if c else 0 for c in row] or [0]) + 1

Comment: Seems like your table does not exist or no items.... Track it from "print table.table"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Attribute Error - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/python-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well few hit and trial and i got my answer.

I changed following

```
albums_list = map(lambda x:[x['album_id'],x['title'], x['language'], x['seokey'], x['release_date'],','.join(map(lambda y:y['name'], x.get('artists',[])[:2])) ,x['trackcount']], albums)
        tabledata = [['S No.', 'Album Title', 'Album Language', 'Release Date', 'Artists', 'Track Count']]
        for idx, value in enumerate(albums_list):
            tabledata.append([str(idx), value[1], value[2], value[4], value[5], value[6]])
```

with

```
        albums_list = map(lambda x:[x['album_id'],x['title'], x['language'], x['seokey'], x['release_date']], albums)
        tabledata = [['S No.', 'Album Title', 'Album Language', 'Release Date']]
        for idx, value in enumerate(albums_list):
            tabledata.append([str(idx), value[1], value[2], value[4]])
```

and it worked fine now :)